# Center component footer in React

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have this footer with a fixed position at the bottom of screen. And I would like it to be 50% width of the screen, and center it.

So here is my component with TailwindCSS :

```
export default class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <footer className="w-1/2 mx-auto fixed h-8 transparent bg-gray-600 bottom-0 flex items-center">
                <div className="flex justify-center w-100">
                    <a href="https://github.com/brazillierjo" className="mx-5" target="blank">
                        <i className="fab fa-github text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                    <Link to="/connexion" className="mx-5">
                        <i className="fas fa-user-plus text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/waletoo" className="mx-5">
                        <i className="fas fa-info-circle text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </footer>
        )
    }
}
```

The class `mx-auto` won't work, but for example `ml-5` (margin-left: 1.25rem) works. I don't understand why ?

EDIT :

Here is my custom CSS :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "SFPro";
    src: url("./fonts/SFProText.ttf") format("ttf"),
   }

   body {
       font-family: "SFPro", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
       width: 100%;
   }

   .shadow-blue {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px lightblue;
  }

  .shadow-red {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px lightcoral;
  }

  .shadow-gray {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px lightgray;
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @konekoya there is one below, in JsWizard response

Comment: Yep, I've seen that one. But it doesn't repro the exact issue you're facing: "it works on tailwind play, but not in my project", I'm guessing that there are some styling are overriding each other and so it doesn't solve your issue

Comment: @konekoya ah yes sorry, I edited my post with all my custom CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with [absolute](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/position#absolute) and [inset-x-0](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/top-right-bottom-left#class-reference)

```
export default class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <footer className="w-1/2 mx-auto h-8 transparent bg-gray-600 bottom-0 items-center absolute inset-x-0">
                <div className="flex justify-center w-100">
                    <a href="https://github.com/brazillierjo" className="mx-5" target="blank">
                        <i className="fab fa-github text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                    <Link to="/connexion" className="mx-5">
                        <i className="fas fa-user-plus text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to="/waletoo" className="mx-5">
                        <i className="fas fa-info-circle text-lg text-white"></i>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </footer>
        )
    }
}
```

***Tailwind Play***  https://play.tailwindcss.com/lp2BsTWUOo

Comment: It works on tailwind play, but not in my project. Would you have an idea why ?

Comment: please replace `class` to `className` if you didn't. and check your parents component css :)

Comment: did you use my example code? could you let me show your screenshot or other css about a point of problem. :)

Comment: yes, I did, it didn't work. So I chose another design for my footer, and I will work on it when my project is done. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can style the footer tag to be at the center of the page.

```
footer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Actually, no. That's what I say in my post, margin:auto does not work